# Rename file so it includes the date

Tags: r

I am currently using `file.rename` and wish to include a `dd.mm.yy` at the very end of the new file name.

```
file.rename('x.xlsx','x DD.MM.YY.xls')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
fname = "x"
date=as.character.Date(format.Date(Sys.Date(),"%d.%m.%y"))
fmt=".xlsx"
newname=paste0(x,date,fmt)
file.rename("x.xlsx",newname)
```

Comment: Thank you. That worked great. is there anyway to edit the fmt to dd.mm.yy ? Also is it possible to use vectors to rename a bunch of different files into a similar format. Such as in the fname section "x" and "y" "z" into c("x","y","z")?

Comment: @Will Edited the code to achieve the desired format. Also, Yes it is possible to use vectors. You will need three vectors within `paste0()` to get the desired newname vector. Check documentation of `file.rename()`. It supports **character** vectors in `from` and `to` arguments.